# дайте идею пет проекта python

Tags: python, intellij-idea, project

Прошёл уже синтаксис и структуры данных на python, нужна хорошая идея первого пет проекта чтоб все темы затронуть.

Comment: Напишите игру "Виселица", там как раз затронуты структуры данных.

Comment: Либо крестики-нолики, но там посложней будет

Comment: Сайт На джанго или телеграм бот

Comment: Голосую за закрытие, оффтоп и не возможно дать объективный ответ

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Рекомендую написать простейшие игры в консоли. Начинайте с простейшей игры "Три двери" (*есть 3 двери, в одной привидение, игра продолжается, пока игрок не открыл дверь с привидением*), заканчивайте ["Крестиками-ноликами"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8) (интересная игра, но могут возникнуть сложности в написании кода) и ["Виселицей"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_(%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0)) (игра, затрагивающая структуры данных). Раньше любил игру [2048](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/2048_(%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0)), попробуйте написать её.

Если хотите немного отвлечься от азов, изучите библиотеки `discord.py` и `aiogram` - они позволяют писать веб-ботов в Дискорде и Телеграме соответственно.

Также настоятельно рекомендую поучить азы `Turtle` и `Tkinter` - с помощью `Tkinter` можно писать графические приложения, а `Turtle` - основы графики.